# The table 'table_name' is full in MySQL

Tags: mysql

One of our INNODB tables contained about 350 million entries. All of a sudden, we started getting the error 'The table 'table_name' is full'. The table contains logs-like entries(click logs, basically). Since we didn't need data that was a year old, as a temporary fix I deleted about 30 million entries. However, since we are getting about 5-6 million entries everyday now, I fear that this error would crop up again. Any thoughts on how to overcome it ?

The specs of the machine are : 48 GB ram, 757 gb SSD. Currently, the used space on disk is 500 gb. 30 % free space.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed in 5.7.4:  A page allocation for an undo log due failed with a “table is full” error message instead of an “undo log is full” error message.

5.6.3 is pre-GA.  Recommend you upgrade at least to a later 5.6.xx.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-undo-logs.html as for a discussion of what can be done about "undo tablespaces" starting with 5.6.3.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you setup a script to run daily that archive older records (this will also reduce the load on that table since you mentioned it has over 300 million rows)

check **percona pt-archiver**